# DropDownList bind from web service Not passing data source when Edit in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am using web service to bind data in DropDownList when I Add New data drop down list working fine, but when I Edit mode drop data source not fill. so the question is how to fill data source when I am using web service to bind web service.

Html:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbFlightNo" class="form-control"  runat="server" DataValueField="mFlightNo" DataTextField="mFlightNo" AppendDataBoundItems="true">

                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

webservies

```
[WebMethod]
public Airline_Flights[] Loadetails(string StuID)
{
    string Conec = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BriskCargo"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conec);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select FlightNo from AirLine_Flights where ALCode='" + StuID + "' and IsActive=1", con);
    DataTable st = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(st);
    List<Airline_Flights> details = new List<Airline_Flights>();
    foreach (DataRow dtrow in st.Rows)
    {
        Airline_Flights obj = new Airline_Flights();
        obj.mFlightNo = dtrow["FlightNo"].ToString();
        details.Add(obj);
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return details.ToArray();
}
```

JQuery code to fill when change when fire.

```
 function Load_Regno() {

       var StuID = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbAirlines').value;
      $.ajax(
        {
        type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           url: "AirlinesDropDown.asmx/Loadetails",
           data: JSON.stringify({StuID: StuID }),
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
             var theDropDown = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbFlightNo");
             theDropDown.length = 0;
             $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                 $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbFlightNo").append($("<option></option>").val(value.mFlightNo).html(value.mFlightNo));
    });
            },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 0) {
        alert(' Check Your Network.');
    } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 404) {
        alert('Requested URL not found.');
    } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 500) {
        alert('Internel Server Error.');
    } else {
        alert('Unknow Error.\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
              }
        });

            return false;
   }
```

Comment: It appears you do not use `JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();` so probably remove that.   Have you checked in debugger, does `return details.ToArray();` contain data?  Sorry for the basic questions, trying to get to point of failure here.  Webforms tend to want you to use the server side methods, update panels etc when bound server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
public Airline_Flights[] Loadetails(string StuID)
{
    var flightsList = GetFlightListByStuID(string StuID);
    return selectedFlights.Select(x => x.FlightNo).ToArray();
}

// could be in another data access class etc.
private List<Airline_Flights> GetFlightListByStuID(string StuID)
{
    List<Airline_Flights> selectedFlights = new List<Airline_Flights>();
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BriskCargo"].ConnectionString;
    // SQL with parameter
    string commandString = @"
       SELECT FlightNo 
       FROM AirLine_Flights 
       WHERE ALCode = @StuID AND IsActive=1
      ";

    // use IDisposable here so it closes and garbage collects automatically
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString))
        {
            // check the length and type here...
            command.Parameters.Add("@StuID",SqlDbType.NVChar, 25).Value = StuID; 
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   flightsList.Add(new Airline_Flights{ FlightNo= reader["FlightNo"].ToString()});
                }
            }
        }  
    }
    return selectedFlights;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function Load_Regno() {
  var StuID = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbAirlines').value;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "AirlinesDropDown.asmx/Loadetails",
      data: {StuID: StuID},
      dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // verify data
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      // or
      console.log(data);
      var theDropDown = $("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbFlightNo");
      theDropDown.html(""); // clear old options
      var options = [];
      $.each(data.d, function(key, value) {
         var opt = ("<option></option>").val(value.FlightNo).html(value.FlightNo))
         options.push(opt); 
      });
      $.each(options,function(v){theDropDown.append(v);});
    })
    .fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 0) {
          alert('Check Your Network.');
        } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 404) {
          alert('Requested URL not found.');
        } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 500) {
          alert('Internal Server Error.');
        } else {
          alert('Unknown Error.\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```